# MySQL - DATE_SUB How to get data's of past years from one date in dynamically

Tags: mysql, database, date

One table is there. That table having the columns are id,fname,date_field.

Date_field column having the records are

```
2011-03-01
2012-03-01
2013-03-01
2014-03-01
2015-03-01
2016-03-01
```

I want the data's before 2 years for each one record from that date which is table having.

Like,
2012 year having only one data before that is 2011

2013 year data having two data before 2 year data which are 2012 and 2011

2014 year data having two data before 2 year data which are 2013 and 2012

2015 year data having two data before 2 year data which are 2014and 2013

2016 year data having two data before 2 year data which are 2015and 2014

Note: Need to work in dynamically whatever the data's in table. Do not give the date in manually.

I want the query in MySQL.

Thanks in advance

Loganath D

Comment: what's your desired output just a count? I think you self join and then do a count

Comment: Yes tin. I want to calculate the average to another one field which is not mentioned in my question. That field name is price..